# What does spark.sql.shuffle.partitions exactly refer to?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

What exactly does `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` refer to? Are we talking of the number of partitions that is the results of a wide transformation, or something that happens in the middle as in some sort of intermediary partitioning before the result partition of the wide transformation?

Because in my understanding, as per a wide transformation we have

```
Parents RDDs -> shuffle files -> Child RDDs
```

What does the spark.sql.shuffle.partitions parameter refer to here? The **shuffles files** or the **CHILD RDDs** or something else that I ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already explained in [the official docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html#other-configuration-options):

> `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`    200     Configures the number of partitions to use when shuffling data for joins or aggregations.

In other words it is the number of partitions of the child `Dataset`.

Comment: I was not sure about making the “in other words” myself, I just wanted a confirmation” thank you